# My sscanf if stuck in an infinite loop, how can I fix it

Tags: c, while-loop, char, scanf, fgets

My goal is to read from `test.txt`, then output its contents. However, the thing is, I get stuck in the sscanf loop. So it keeps reading `Australia` over and over again

test.txt

```
    Australia   Sydney Perth Brisbane
    USA  California Los-Angeles Silicon-Valley Dallas
    Canada  Toronto
```

Excepted output

```
Country: Australia
Cities: Sydney Perth Brisbane
---------------
Country: USA
Cities: California Los-Angeles Silicon-Valley Dallas
---------------
Country: Canada
Cities: Toronto
---------------
```

My code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 2000

int main (void) {

   FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt" ,"r");
   char buf[MAX + 1];
   char country[MAX];
   char city[MAX];

   while (fgets(buf, MAX, fp) != NULL) {

      sscanf(buf, "%s", country);
      printf("Country: %s\n", country);

      printf("Cities:");
      while (sscanf(buf, "%s", city) == 1) {
         printf(" %s", city);
      }

      printf("\n---------------\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would `sscanf` on a non-empty string ever return `EOF`?

Comment: @melpomene I changed it to `1`. I still keep reading Australia over and over again

Comment: Yes, because you put it in a loop. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @melpomene When it reached the end of buf, I expected it would exit the loop, then read the next line. Then read every word in the sscanf loop. What would I need to change to get my expected output?

Comment: `sscanf` does not modify the buffer it reads from.

Comment: @melpomene is there a function I can use which changes the pointer where it starts to read from each time it is called?

Comment: Yes, `strtok()`.

Comment: Aside: no need for one less than the buffer size in `fgets(buf, MAX, fp)`.  Suggest `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)`.

Answer (score 1):

You enter an infinite loop because you are attempting to parse every `city` from the same place you parsed `country` -- the beginning of `buf`. To use `sscanf` to incrementally parse whitespace separated string from `buf`, you need to additionally use the `"%n"` conversion specifier to obtain the number of characters (`nchar` below) consumed by `sscanf` on each read. You can then add that to an offset (`off` below) to successively parse each `city` from `buf` following parsing the `country`.

The approach is straight-forward, use `sscanf` with the `"%s%n"` format string to parse the whitespace delimited string into an array saving the number of characters read/consumed by `sscanf` in an integer variable. For example:

```
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {             /* read each line */
        int nchar = 0;
        char cc[MAXC] = ""; /* buffer for country/city */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%s%n", cc, &nchar)) { /* parse country, get used */
            int off = nchar;                    /* add used char to offset */
            printf ("%s\n", cc);
            /* read each city getting used chars to add to offset */
            while (sscanf (buf + off, "%s%n", cc, &nchar) == 1) {
                printf ("  %s\n", cc);
                off += nchar;
            }
        }
    }
```

Above `buf + off` provides the location in `buf` to begin parsing each city. Also note the use of `"%n"` does NOT increase the conversion count (e.g. the `sscanf` return).

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 2048   /* good use of constanst, but avoid common MAX */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {             /* read each line */
        int nchar = 0;
        char cc[MAXC] = ""; /* buffer for country/city */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%s%n", cc, &nchar)) { /* parse country, get used */
            int off = nchar;                    /* add used char to offset */
            printf ("%s\n", cc);
            /* read each city getting used chars to add to offset */
            while (sscanf (buf + off, "%s%n", cc, &nchar) == 1) {
                printf ("  %s\n", cc);
                off += nchar;
            }
        }
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rdcountrycity <dat/countrycity.txt
Australia
  Sydney
  Perth
  Brisbane
USA
  California
  Los-Angeles
  Silicon-Valley
  Dallas
Canada
  Toronto
```

While using `sscanf` to parse the country and cities from each line of text is fine, there is a tool better suited for the job, e.g. `strtok` which is used to tokenize a sting into tokens based on the delimiters you provide. You can provide delimiters of `" \t\n"` (space, tab, newline) to simply parse each whitespace delimited word from each line.

It's actually much simpler, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 2048       /* good use of constanst, but avoid common MAX */
#define DELIM " \t\n"   /* you can define character contstants too */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {             /* read each line */
        char *p = buf;
        if ((p = strtok (buf, DELIM))) {        /* tokenize country */
            printf ("%s\n", p);
            while ((p = strtok (NULL, DELIM)))  /* tokenize each city */
                printf ("  %s\n", p);
        }
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

(the output is the same)

(**note:** `strtok` **modifies** the original string, so you will need to make a copy of `buf` to preserve the original if required)

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an integer offset, call it `off`, then pass `buf + off` as the first argument of `sscanf` instead of just `buf`:

```
printf("Cities:");

int off = 0;
while (sscanf(buf + off, "%s", city) == 1) {
    printf(" %s", city);
    off += strlen(city);
}
```

As `for`:

```
int off;
for (off = 0; sscanf(buf + off, "%s", city) == 1; off += strlen(city))
    printf(" %s", city);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `%s` can skip over arbitrary many characters (leading whitespace), which won't be counted as part of `city`.

Comment: @melpomene Another part of the program can be tasked with input validation. So the precondition for the parse function will be that the input is valid

Comment: What does that have to do with what I wrote?

Comment: @melpomene Because the input validation stage can trim excess whitespace. This way we can simplify the calculation of offset, not needing to account for spurious whitespace

Comment: That's more complicated than just parsing words manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a buffer overflow, which is dangerous.

When you read from a long line, the `line` may not end in `\n`. If that line doesn't contain any whitespace, the `city` buffer cannot hold the complete line.